# Java class does not recognize indexing

Tags: java, arrays

I  made a Matrix class in JAVA that consists of a 2D int array with row and column variables. The constructor of the class generates a Matrix of dimensions n x m and I also implemented two methods that print the values of the Matrix and its transpose (`getMatrixValues` and `getTransposedValues`).

However, I would like to make a function that takes as input a matrix and returns its transpose, but since this class is not an array I cannot iterate over it using `AT[j][i] = A[i][j]`, if I understand the exception correctly that IntelliJ is returning me ("*java: array required, but Matrix found*").
Obviously, I could simply use an int[][] class to begin with instead of defining a new class, but since I am new to JAVA and object-oriented programming in general I wondered whether there is not another possibility without discarding my Matrix class?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Matrix {


    private int n; // rows
    private int m; // cols
    private int[][] A; // matrix

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Matrix A = new Matrix(4,4);

        A.getMatrixValues();

        System.out.println("\n");
        
        A.getTransposedValues();
        
        Matrix AT = transposeMatrix(A);     
    }

    // constructor (randomly generates matrix)
    public Matrix(int rows, int cols){

        n = rows;
        m = cols;

        A = new int[rows][cols];

        Random r = new Random();
//        r.setSeed(1);

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols ; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = r.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
    }

    // print matrix
    public void getMatrixValues(){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[i][j]+"\t");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    // print transposed matrix
    public void getTransposedValues(){
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(A[j][i]+"\t");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }


    public static Matrix transposeMatrix(Matrix A){

        Matrix AT = new Matrix(A.get_n(), A.get_m());

        for(int i = 0; i < A.get_n(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < A.get_m(); j++)
            {
                AT[j][i] = A[i][j];
            }
        }

    return AT;
    }

    // getters
    public int get_n(){
        return n;
    }

    public int get_m(){
        return m;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unrelated: use names that mean something for your fields (for anything you do, actually). Why do you write `private int n; // rows` instead of just `private int rows`?! Every time you add such a comment to explain your name ... then probably that name is bad and deserves to be improved. Also note that you only use the "_" underscore for SOME_CONSTANT, method names go camel case like, `getN() ` instead.

Comment: That last part is just naming convention. It is not wrong per se, but teachers might find it wrong, and you will confuse many Java-programmers when using it. Your `get_n()` is in so-called "snake_case", but Java's naming convention is generally "camelCase".

Comment: I will keep that in mind, I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**
What I have noticed only afterwards was, that when creating the transposed matrix, you actually want to create one with m-rows and n-columns.
That means, you have mixed up `m` and `n` in `transposeMatrix()` when instantiating the new object.
That *also* means that your code -as it is- only works for square matrices. Just create the object like this: `new Matrix(matrix.get_m(), matrix.get_n())`.
**Note:** I re-named your variables; see below in section "Solution".

However, since this is not part of you question, I have not fixed it in the code-snippets below.

**Scopes**
When in every other method, you are in the lexical scope of the object you are in. This allows you to access its fields (like `int[][] A`).

But when inside `transposeMatrix(Matrix A)`, you are inside the `static` scope, meaning, not in the scope of an object.
What adds to the confusion is, that your instance-variable is called `A`, much like the parameter `Matrix A` of `transposeMatrix()`. While you were able to access the 2D-array via `A`, you now access a `Matrix`-object via `A`. That is both because we are not in an object anymore, and because the new local variable overrides the access to the similarly named instance-/static-variable (you would have to use `this.A` or `Matrix.A` respectively).

**Access modifier**
When trying to fix your code, you will stumble upon the restriction of the access modifier you used: `private`.
`private int[][] A` will make `A` (your array) only accessible when referenced from inside your object. But when calling `transposeMatrix()`, we are in a static-context, meaning, not inside your object anymore.

To fix this, can change the access modifier to allow us to access that field from outside the object. To enable this, you can change the modifier to *any other* option, with the easiest being to just remove it. However, I suggest you to read more about [Access Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) in the official documentation.

**Solution**
Let's say we removed `private` from `int[][] A`. Will the code work?
No. That's because of the confusion I talked about when explaining scopes. To clear up the confusion, let's rename some variables: (Changed `int[][] A` to `int[][] array`, `Matrix A` to `Matrix matrix`, `Matrix AT` to `Matrix matrixTransposed`)

```java
int[][] array; // <-- Notice the removed access modifier!

// ...

public static Matrix transposeMatrix(Matrix matrix){
  Matrix matrixTransposed = new Matrix(matrix.get_n(), matrix.get_m());

  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_n(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.get_m(); j++) {
      matrixTransposed[j][i] = matrix[i][j]; // Won't work!
    }
  }
}
```

The code above is still faulty. That is -as we can clearly see now- because we are trying to access a `Matrix`-object as if it was an array. However, we need to access its *instance variable*. So, instead of accessing the array the wrong way, we add a `.array` after every `Matrix`-object where we try to access its array.

```java
public static Matrix transposeMatrix(Matrix matrix){
  Matrix matrixTransposed = new Matrix(matrix.get_n(), matrix.get_m());

  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_n(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.get_m(); j++) {
      matrixTransposed.array[j][i] = matrix.array[i][j]; // NOW we are accessing their arrays respectively
    }
  }
}
```

**Another solution**
With changing the access modifier of the array (like we did above), we enable one to not only override the values of the array, but also to override *the array itself*.
To restrict one from doing so, we can use "Getters and Setters". They are like a middle-man, allowing us to access the array only indirectly, but with that much control over it as we seem necessary.

We can define them simply creating two new methods (hence its name):

```java
public int get(int i, int j) {
  return array[i][j];
}
public void set(int i, int j, int value) {
  array[i][j] = value;
}
```

As you see, we simply forward the request to the "middle-man", which handles it accordingly.
**Note:** We might encounter a [Runtime Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) since we are not checking if the fields at the specified indices actually exist. You might want to add some if-statements before accessing them.

By using the getter and setter, we can modify the code to this:

```java
private int[][] array; // We still want to restrict access to 'array'...

// ...

// ...but still allow accessing them, be it indirectly
public int get(int i, int j) {
  return array[i][j];
}
public void set(int i, int j, int value) {
  array[i][j] = value;
}

// Now using getter and setter
public static Matrix transposeMatrix(Matrix matrix) {
  Matrix matrixTransposed = new Matrix(matrix.get_n(), matrix.get_m);

  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.get_n(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.get_m; j++) {
      matrixTransposed.set(j, i, matrix.get(i, j));
    }
  }
}
```

**Sidenote**
You should also take a look at [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). They are not critical to make your code function, but make reading and understanding (and thus debugging) it a lot easier.

What I think is also good, is to take a look at a style-guide to see how you can make your code more readible with easy tricks, or just to have a consistent style across your code. I enjoy [Google's style-guide for Java](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), however, there are a lot others as well.
And, you don't have to stick to an existing style-guide, you can have your own style, too! But try to be as consistent as possible. That makes it easier for others *and* yourself in the future when re-reading your code.